# PassportJS Google Auth in MERN not working

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, authentication, passport.js

So I am trying to login with Google authentication in MERN,
using passportjs but it doesn't seem to do anything at all.

Like when I redirect to /auth/google it doesn't do anything.

Anyone had the same problem and fixed it or know how to?

Here is my code:

Configuration:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
var passport = require('passport');
var Strategy = require('passport-google-oauth').OAuth2Strategy;

const GoogleStrategy = passport.use(new Strategy({
    clientID: 'Cant show for security reason',
    clientSecret: 'Cant show for security reason',
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/google/callback"
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
       User.findOrCreate({ googleId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
         return done(err, user);
       });
  }
));


module.exports = GoogleStrategy;
```

Configuration 2:

```
const passport  = require('passport');
const User = require('../models/user')

passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user.email);
  });

  passport.deserializeUser(function (email, done) {
    User.findOne({ email }).exec((err, user) => {
        done(err, user);

    })
});

const SigninGoogleStrategy = require('./GoogleAuth')
const SigninStrategy = require('./SigninStrategy');
const SignupStrategy = require('./SignupStrategy');

passport.use('google',SigninGoogleStrategy)
passport.use('local-signin', SigninStrategy);
passport.use('local-signup', SignupStrategy);

module.exports = passport;
```

Route:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express.Router();
const passport = require('../passport')

app.get('/auth/google',
  passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login'] }));

app.get('/auth/google/callback', 
  passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
  function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/profile');
  });

module.exports = app;
```

Some of jsx code:

```
                    <a href="/auth/google" className="button">
                    <div>
                        <span className="svgIcon t-popup-svg">
                        <svg className="svgIcon-use" width={25} height={37} viewBox="0 0 25 25">
                            <g fill="none" fillRule="evenodd">
                            <path d="M20.66 12.693c0-.603-.054-1.182-.155-1.738H12.5v3.287h4.575a3.91 3.91 0 0 1-1.697 2.566v2.133h2.747c1.608-1.48 2.535-3.65 2.535-6.24z" fill="#4285F4" />
                            <path d="M12.5 21c2.295 0 4.22-.76 5.625-2.06l-2.747-2.132c-.76.51-1.734.81-2.878.81-2.214 0-4.088-1.494-4.756-3.503h-2.84v2.202A8.498 8.498 0 0 0 12.5 21z" fill="#34A853" />
                            <path d="M7.744 14.115c-.17-.51-.267-1.055-.267-1.615s.097-1.105.267-1.615V8.683h-2.84A8.488 8.488 0 0 0 4 12.5c0 1.372.328 2.67.904 3.817l2.84-2.202z" fill="#FBBC05" />
                            <path d="M12.5 7.38c1.248 0 2.368.43 3.25 1.272l2.437-2.438C16.715 4.842 14.79 4 12.5 4a8.497 8.497 0 0 0-7.596 4.683l2.84 2.202c.668-2.01 2.542-3.504 4.756-3.504z" fill="#EA4335" />
                            </g>
                        </svg>
                        </span>
                        <span className="button-label">Sign in with Google</span>
                    </div>
                    </a>
```

Comment: Are you getting an error message of some sort somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive but I think your problem might be in your configuration/configuration2 (I'm assuming these are different configurations for your passport?). Configuration looks good if you just add some code to it from configuration 2.

```
const passport = require('passport');
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth').OAuth2Strategy;

passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});

passport.use(
    new GoogleStrategy(
        {
            clientID:'secretClientID',
            clientSecret: 'enterClientSecret',
            callbackURL: 'http://localhost:3000/auth/google/callback',
        },
        function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
            var userData = {
                email: profile.emails[0].value,
                name: profile.displayName,
                token: accessToken,
            };
            done(null, userData);
        },
    ),
);
```

Again, I'm not 100% on my answer but maybe try this and see if it helps. Best of luck!